# How to read and process a directory multithread using thread pool in SpringBoot

Tags: java, multithreading, file, threadpool

I have a java application that fetches all files in a directory and reads these files one by one.

```
public Set<String> processDirectory(String filePath) {
    Set<String> setResult = new Set<>();
    try (LineIterator iterator = FileUtils.lineIterator(new File(filePath))) {
        while (iterator.hasNext()) {
            String fileLine = iterator.nextLine();
            // do something with fileLine and store the result in setResult
        }
    }
    return setResult;
}
```

I want that given a thread pool of size 3, every thread will process the method processDirectory and store the results into a set.

I'm using Spring boot and I was wondering what is the best practice to implement this.

I'm a bit lost with all the tutorials I found on the Net.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest use Spring batch reader/process/writer huge files efficiently with spring boot

Click [here] (https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/current/reference/html/readersAndWriters.html)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).